# Values in first Column are not showing properly in sql

Tags: mysql, csv, sqldatatypes, codio

When I run a Select * query for my table the values in the OrderID do not show up. I suspect this has something to do with the Description column which is the last column in my table. When I omit that column the values in OrderID appear. I did need to update the VARCHAR from 50 to 100 characters because I received a truncated error message when importing a csv file into the database. I'm including the syntax for
review.

```
describe Orders;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| OrderID     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| CustomerID  | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| SKU         | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Description | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

mysql> select * from Orders limit 50;
+---------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| OrderID | CustomerID | SKU        | Description                                        |
+---------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------+
            |    76368 | BAS-08-1 C | Basic Switch  10/100/1000 BaseT 8 port
            |    62494 | BAS-48-1 C | Basic Switch 10/100/1000 BaseT 48 port
             |   98077 | ENT-48-10F | Enterprise Switch 10GigE SFP+ 48 port
            |    85882 | ENT-48-40F | Enterprise Switch 40GigE SFP+ 48 port 
            |    59384 | BAS-48-1 C | Basic Switch 10/100/1000 BaseT 48 port
             |   96361 | ENT-48-10F | Enterprise Switch 10GigE SFP+ 48 port
|      15 |      67424 | ADV-48-10F | Advanced Switch 10 GigE Copper/Fiber 44 port coppe |
             |   93634 | ENT-24-10F | Enterprise Switch 10GigE SFP+ 24 Port
            |    62756 | ENT-24-40F | Enterprise Switch 40GigE SFP+ 24 port 
            |    99453 | BAS-48-1 C | Basic Switch 10/100/1000 BaseT 48 port

             |   98965 | ENT-48-10F | Enterprise Switch 10GigE SFP+ 48 port
|      33 |      87899 | ADV-48-10F | Advanced Switch 10 GigE Copper/Fiber 44 port coppe 

mysql> SELECT OrderID, CustomerID, SKU FROM Orders limit 10;
+---------+------------+------------+
| OrderID | CustomerID | SKU        |
+---------+------------+------------+
|       0 |      76368 | BAS-08-1 C |
|       2 |      62494 | BAS-48-1 C |
|       6 |      98077 | ENT-48-10F |
|       8 |      85882 | ENT-48-40F |
|      10 |      59384 | BAS-48-1 C |
|      14 |      96361 | ENT-48-10F |
|      15 |      67424 | ADV-48-10F |
```

Answer (score 0):

The column `description` was generated on some Windows app, and has Carriage Return (CR - `\r`) at the end.

When displayed in the non-Windows app, the CR runs back to the beginning of the line, wiping out some things.

Note how two of the lines correctly show the OrderId.  In those cases, `description` seems to be truncated.  That is the CR was lopped off.

What to do...

- Live with the issue
- Use a different way to display the results
- Trim any string columns before storing them in the table.  (There are many possible ways to "trim"; need to know where the data is coming from and how the `INSERTs` are performed.)
- Instead of `SELECT * ...`, spell out the columns:  `SELECT OrderId, CustomerId, SKU, TRIM(description) ...`  (I'm not sure if this will work.)